# react-native TransformError when requiring a node_module that has a package.json with a babel config that specifies uninstalled plugin

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I try to use the package [`es6-error`](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/es6-error) in a react native app.

The packager fails with

```
[node-haste] Encountered an error while persisting cache:
> ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "add-module-exports" specified in "/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/es6-error/package.json" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/es6-error"
>     at /home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:220:17
>     at Array.map (native)
>     at Function.normalisePlugins (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:196:20)
>     at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:317:36)
>     at OptionManager.addConfig (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:248:10)
>     at OptionManager.findConfigs (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:460:30)
>     at OptionManager.init (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:502:12)
>     at File.initOptions (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:243:89)
>     at new File (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:159:72)
> TransformError: /home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/es6-error/lib/index.js: Unknown plugin "add-module-exports" specified in "/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/es6-error/package.json" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/es6-error"
[node-haste] Encountered an error while persisting cache:
> ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "add-module-exports" specified in "/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/es6-error/package.json" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/es6-error"
>     at /home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:220:17
>     at Array.map (native)
>     at Function.normalisePlugins (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:196:20)
>     at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:317:36)
>     at OptionManager.addConfig (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:248:10)
>     at OptionManager.findConfigs (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:460:30)
>     at OptionManager.init (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:502:12)
>     at File.initOptions (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:243:89)
>     at new File (/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:159:72)
> TransformError: /home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/es6-error/lib/index.js: Unknown plugin "add-module-exports" specified in "/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/es6-error/package.json" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/home/jwerner/veloyo/veloyo/partner/node_modules/es6-error"
```

The error seems to be that the es6-error specifies its babel configuration in its [package.json](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/es6-error/blob/master/package.json).

While i found workarounds for the case that the package would have specified the babel config via `.babelrc` (post-install hook that deletes the given `.babelrc` files) i haven't been able to fix this error.

Any pointers?

My versions:

```
❯ react-native --version
react-native-cli: 0.1.10
react-native: 0.27.0-rc

❯ node -v
v5.1.1

❯ npm -v
3.8.3
```

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @MikaA. Or poster, have you found a solution? I have a similar issue.

Comment: I removed my node_modules folder and re-installed all packages. There is a clear cache command as well for this but I don't exactly remember it.